# SQL Query for Access Pie chart - Group By one field but group certain values

Tags: sql, ms-access, pie-chart

Trying to **automatically** produce a `piechart` in access which will show me 3 values (completed, pending and queued)
However in my status field I have several values for pending (**sent, monitoringStage1, monitoringStage2, finalApproval**)

My query at present gives me the count of each item individually:

```
SELECT Status, Count(*) AS [Count]
FROM StatusTable
GROUP BY Status
ORDER BY Status;
```

How would I edit it to **count sent, monitoringStage1, monitoringStage2, and finalApproval** as one item called pending?

Also on a side note, does anybody know how to put a line at a certain point on a piechart by percentage? So in the piechart created I could have a line to indicate the target number of completed items to compare against current progress.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use CASE in a query, only in VBA.

This will take care of it:

```
SELECT qryTestx.ThisStatus, Count(qryTestx.Status) AS CountOfStatus
FROM  (SELECT (IIf([StatusTable.Status] in ("sent","monitoringStage1","monitoringStage2","finalApproval"),"Pending",[StatusTable.Status])) AS ThisStatus, StatusTable.Status
FROM StatusTable) qryTestx
GROUP BY qryTestx.ThisStatus;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and don't forget to vote ;)

```
select 

count(*),
case 
when Status  in ( 'sent', 'monitoringStage1', 'monitoringStage2', 'finalApproval') then 'pending'
else status
end as status

from StatusTable 

group by
case 
when Status  in ( 'sent', 'monitoringStage1', 'monitoringStage2', 'finalApproval') then 'pending'
else status
end
```

Comment: Syntax error - missing operator in query expression. - Any idea's?

Comment: Can you show me the query you used, it is probably not going to be the same as what I wrote(I hope not) as I do not have you tables to test this on.

Comment: Johnny Bones said "You can't use CASE in a query" - that's strange, I use case statements in lots of SQL queries and they always work...